# Sum in Report Viewer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, rdlc, reportviewer

[This is a rough illustration 1st part.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvwfP.png)

I subscribe to the subreport from my main report. Now the subreport handler function decides the data in the subreport. The 3 data in the subreport are of int type. Also the Data1 is the parameter for the subreport. So you understand that the number of Data1 values in column1 determines the number of subreports generated.

[Rough illustration final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAUQJ.png)

How do I calulate the sum as shown in the figure?

Comment: I would make it into another subreport with values calculated separately.